# Android: draw a line of a certain length

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a relative layout with multiple textViews next to each other. I used android:toLeftOf for positioning these textViews. So let's say I have 5 textViews in one line, what I want now is to draw a line below these textViews, it should start at the left corner of the left textView and end at the right corner of the right textView. Like this:

```
  tv1 tv2 tv3 tv4 tv5   
  -------------------
```

It should be  a solid line not a dashed line. I thought of a patch 9 graphic but how would I determine the length of the line? Any idea how to accomplish this? Each textView has a certain size, padding, etc.

Comment: you can add a imageView with align left and layout_below of left text view align right with right most text view

Comment: you can use an empty view with your line height, as Oam answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="#000000" />
```

This displays a horizontal line with black background. Hope it helps.

Comment: this works plus the response from lftikar Urrhman Khan, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the TextViews in a ViewGroup and then add the 9 Patch as a background image.